# C++ linked list always needs 2 classes?

Tags: c++, linked-list

The examples I've found so far, show a linked list as class of a Node in a class of a linked list:

```cpp
class Node
{
  public:
    const Id id;    // unique identifier, never changes
    Data data;      // set of multiple data fields that can be updated/changed
  private:
    Node* next;
}
class NodeList
{
  public:
    NodeList():head(NULL){}
    ˜NodeList();
    void AddToNodeList(const Id id, Data data);      // add node with id & data to list
    void RemoveFromNodeList(const Id id);            // unique id to find node and remove
    void UpdateDataNodelist(const Id id, Data data); // update data of unique id
    void DisplayNodeList();                          // display all id's and their data
  private:
    Node* head;
}
```

First of all, doesn't the Node class need a constructor & destructor? And while we're at it, do I explicitly need to define a copy-constructor or is the implicit one just fine? And finally, my main question, do you need to create two separate classes or can you also squeeze it in one class? Or does that make the code messy, complex and less flexible?

Comment: Rule of five: if you declare any of these, you should declare/delete all of them: destructor, copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, move constructor, move-assignment operator.

Comment: Well, [`<forward_list>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) only takes one (template) class, and using it instead of rolling your own non-standard list implementation *definitely* makes your code *less* messy, complex, and inflexible. ;-)

Comment: Separating the list and nodes makes the code more modular and easier to handle. It separates implementation and is a way to use [the single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Comment: Three questions is about two more than what is called for by this site's standards. Also, do you mean "need" (as in the code will malfunction without it) or just "recommended" (as in the code could function fine, but it's much harder than it needs to be).

Comment: Thanks for all suggestion and the reference to the site's standard. I'll keep improving!